# How to handle an Unwrap optional value

Tags: ios, swift, optional-values

```
    if messages[i].header == nil || messages[i].header.sender == nil || messages[i].header.sender.displayName == nil{
                snd = "No Name"
                }
                else
                { snd =  messages[i].header.sender.displayName
                }
```

since i got solution of my answer if you have more then 1 values who become nil messages[i] == nill or may be sender could be nill or displayname == nill so for this we have to use or condition to check indiviually

Comment: What types are `messages`, `messages[i]`, `messages[i].header`, `messages[i].header.sender` and `messages[i].header.sender.displayName`? Is there an implicitly unwrapped optional somewhere in the middle of that chain?

Comment: i am fetching an email sender display name and currently it fetch all sender display name but an single mail with  no display name gives nill which is true so i am handling it by providing hard quoted value  messages is all mail messages assigne to messages variable it gives me only one value from if condtion

Comment: You didn't answer my question.

Comment: messages mean all mails in message right messages[i] mean i am fetching all messages in for loop one by one messages[i].header mean a that message header and messages[i].header.displayname mean that specific mail display name totaly it give me ans like "Youtube" or "facebook" or "anyperson who send me mail its display name" but in my mail account there is one mail which  dont have displayname thats why its give nil so i am handling it by giving an optional value butt still its crash on if condition its doesnot go on else part

Comment: Again, you didn't answer my question. What TYPES are these expressions?

Comment: i did these expression fetch all emails for example u send me an email  and in ur email there is no display name in it only when i fetch ur email with no display name its give error because there is no display name in ur email

Comment: I understand, but you STILL have not answer my question. What is the TYPE of `messages`? Is it `Array<String>`? Is it `Array<Data>`? Is it `SomeOtherCollection<SomeMessageType>`? ***What type is it?*** And what about `messages[i]`? What is the type of that? How about `messages[i].header`, and so on...

Comment: messages type is [mcoimapmessages]  its contain email messages  its basically an data type of email messages provided by the mailcore2 library for email handling app see my updated question

Comment: Okay, good start. And it's not `[mcoimapmessages]`, it's `[MCOIMAPMessage]`. What type is `messages[i].header`?

Comment: messages[i].header mean a specific email header which is type of [McoIMAPmessage]  and normally it is String

Comment: Farhan, you have to understand... I'm not askign what purpose these things serve, i'm asking about their Type, so far as the Swift language and compiler are concerned. I can read English, it's ***obvious***  that `message.header` is the message's header. Of Course! What's not obvious, is exactly what type that is. You say it's "normally String". What does that mean? "Normally" string?

Comment: sorry for not  clearing am sorry message.header is string  message[i].header.sender also a string type to more extend it messages[i].header.sender.displayname it whole return string type

Comment: Are you ***sure*** that `message[i].header` is `String`? Because that doesn't make sense. `message[i].header.sender` would not be possible, because `String` does not have a `sender` property.

Comment: message[i].header.sender its give answer for example farhan.ahmed@gmail.com (message[i].header.sender) access messages sender name  which is  return String type

Comment: This is getting very frustrating. You're answering questions I'm not asking. I didn't ask about `message[i].header.sender`. I won't help you if you keep ignoring what I'm asking. I ask about `message[i].header`. For the last time. ***What is the type of `message[i].header.sender`?***

Comment: if you turn chat on so might be i could make you understand easily ?

Comment: I can't, you don't have the reputation necessary to participate in chat. But it's not an issue of how we're communicating, it's an issue of you not answering the very clear, straight forward questions i'm asking you.

Comment: its [McoIMAPMessages] type .header .sender is property of [McoIMAPMessages] still you did not understand or i could not make make you understand i ll ask to my university professor and then i ll tell you thanks alot for your time brother

Comment: Yes, `header` is a property of `MCOIMAPMessage`, I understand that. BUT WHAT TYPE IS THAT PROPERTY?!

Comment: Also, you're being very careless, you really need to pay closer attention to detail. It's `MCOIMAPMessage`, not `McoIMAPMessages`. And it's a property of `MCOIMAPMessage`, not on `[MCOIMAPMessage]` (which is `Array<MCOIMAPMessage>`. Such an array doesn't have a `header` property, the `MCOIMAPMessage` elements of the array have `header` properties)

Comment: header is String Type property of MCOIMAPMessage

Comment: am sorry with the typing am new with swift and stakoverflow

Comment: `String` doesn't have `date`, `subject` or `sender` properties, so things like `messages[i].header.date` can't be possible if `header` was a `String`. `header` can't possibly be a `String`.  Can you please just actually check what type `header` is

Answer (score 1):

You should really take some care into cleaning up your formatting. It's sloppy. Also, you should use `if let` to conditionally unwrap and bind the value inside an optional, if it exists`:

```
if let displayName = messages[i].header.sender.displayName {
    snd = displayName
}
else {
    snd = "No Name"
}
```

Even better, you can use [the nil-coalescing operator (`??`)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html):

```
let snd = messages[i].header.sender.displayName ?? "No Name"
```

In response to your edited question. Again, you're code is a complete mess. This code makes it look like it costs you money to type letters. `msgs`? `snd`? `sbj`? Really? Is `messages`, `sender`, `subject` that much harder to write? Think of how much cleaner and easier they are for the *readers* of your code. Without even fixing it yet, just look at how much more manageable this code is after some clean-up:

```
fetchOperation?.start { (error, messages, vanished) -> Void in
    let sender = "No Name"
    if messages != nil {
        let messages = msgs as! [MCOIMAPMessage]
        for i in 0..<messages.count {
            let dateString = messages[i].header.date.description
            let subject = messages[i].header.subject!
            print(subject)//HERE ITS GIVE ME SBJ THTS MEAN NO NIL IN IT NIL COMES  when i used for display name
            let sender = messages[i].header?.sender?.displayName? ?? "No Name"
            //its give fetal error unwrap optional value for "snd"
        }
    }
}
```

Now, here's my attempt at fixing it up:

```
fetchOperation?.start { (error, messages, vanished) -> Void in
    guard let messages = messages as? [MCOIMAPMessage] else { return }
    for message in messages {
        let header = message.header

        //FIXME: .description is a bad idea. use dateformatter to internationalize.
        let dateString = header.date.description 
        let subject = header.subject
        print(subject)
        let senderDisplayName = header.sender.displayName ?? "No Name"
    }
}
```

Comment: its strange i used  let snd = messages[i].header.sender.displayName ?? "No Name" but still it says fetal error unwrap an optional value

Answer (score 1):

In this long chain, I suspect that you have a nil

```
messages[i].header.sender.displayName
```

Meaning, perhaps `header` or `sender` or even `messages[i]` is nil. However, normally the compiler will yell at you so that you wind up writing something that looks like:

```
messages?[i].header?.sender?.displayName == nil
```

or similar; depending on how many of the items in the chain of keys are optionals.

Meaning, the correct chain might be

```
messages[i].header?.sender.displayName
```

or

```
messages[i].header.sender?.displayName
```

or

```
messages?[i].header?.sender.displayName
```

etc. All depending on your data model and which of those items are defined as optionals.

Comment: Exactly, there's probably an implicitly unwrapped optional somewhere along the chain, that's being implicitly unwrapped. OP needs to tell us what the types of these intermediate expressions are.

Comment: i have already check if messages is nil then under the if condtion i go inside next if thts mean messages[i] is not nill

Comment: var snd = "No Name"
            if msgs != nil {
                var messages=msgs as! [MCOIMAPMessage]
                for i in 0..<messages.count
                {
        let date:String = messages[i].header.date.description
                   let sbj = messages[i].header.subject!
                    print(sbj)//here its print subjct perfactly 
    let snd = messages[i].header?.sender?.displayName? ?? "No Name"
}